# Sub to create object of type passed by caller in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm having trouble creating a sub that can create objects of a variable type on the fly. Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class systemSettings
    'some properties
end class

Class fireSystemSettings
    inherits systemSettings
    'some additional properties
end class

Class windSystemSettings
    inherits systemSettings
    'some additional properties
end class

sub createSystem(systemType as Type, arg1 as object, arg2 as object)
    Dim newSystem as New systemType(arg1, arg2)
    systemCollection.add(newSystem)
end sub
```

I can't get it to work. I've done a fair bit of research, and looked at generic types, reflection, and other tools, but I'm having trouble determining how best to tackle this problem.

Comment: Consider using generics instead of `Type`, if you can.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for `Activator.CreateInstance(systemType)`

Comment: Can this handle a constructor? I edited my original post to show that New takes 2 arguments, a fact i neglected to show originally.

Comment: There is an overload that takes an array of objects for the constructor params. `Activator.CreateInstance(SomeType, New Object() {Param1, Param2})`

Answer (score 4):

Use generics for this:

```
Sub createSystem(Of T As {New, systemSettings})()
    Dim newSystem As New T
    systemCollection.add(newSystem)
End Sub
```

And call it with:

```
createSystem(Of windSystem)
```

To explain:

The term `Of T` lets you create a method that can be used for any type.  Every time you call it for a new value of T, a new method is created in memory.

The term `As {New, systemSettings}` constrains `T`.  It says that T must represent a type that is or derives from `systemSettings`.  It also says that `T` must contain a default constructor: `New()` which is required for the command `New T`.  Note that you cannot specify a more elaborate constructor as a generics constraint.

If you require parameters in your constructor, you can create an `Initialise` method in the base class.  Because `T` is constrained to `systemSettings`, it is guaranteed that the `Initialise` method exists.

```
Class systemSettings   
    Public Overridable Sub Initialise(arg1 As Object, arg2 As Object)
        'initialise properties
    End Sub
    'some properties   
End class   

Class fireSystemSettings   
    Inherits systemSettings   
    Public Overrides Sub Initialise(arg1 As Object, arg2 As Object)
        'initialise properties
    End Sub
    'some additional properties   
End Class   

Class windSystemSettings   
    Inherits systemSettings   
    Public Overrides Sub Initialise(arg1 As Object, arg2 As Object)
        'initialise properties
    End Sub
    'some additional properties   
End Class   

Sub createSystem(Of T As {New, systemSettings})(arg1 As Object, arg2 As Object)
    Dim newSystem As New T
    newSystem.Initialise(arg1, arg2)
    systemCollection.add(newSystem)
End Sub
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly this method essentially creates another method which inherits the original, but modifies the parameters type?
This is interesting, however i neglected to show in my original post that new takes two arguments, and it seems from your last statement this solution will not work.

Comment: That's correct.  See my answer for a solution to your new problem.